# Remove duplicate text in string Function

Tags: string, function, ms-access, duplicates, vba

I have a function to remove duplicate text strings in a single column of an Access table:

Original values:  Cardholder, Reconciler, Reconciler, Cardholder, Approver

Desired output: Cardholder, Reconciler, Approver.

I have the following function that accomplishes that, but it leaves a hanging comma if there is only one value to return (e.g. "Cardholder, ")

```
Function stringOfUniques(inputString As String) As String
        Dim inArray() As String
        Dim xVal As Variant
        Dim s As String
        inArray = Split(inputString, ",")
        For Each xVal In inArray
            If InStr(s, Trim(xVal)) = 0 Then _
            s = s & Trim(xVal) & " ,"
        Next xVal
        stringOfUniques = s
    End Function
```

What part should be adjusted to reflect that change?

Thanks.

Comment: Just grab the last element of your array and replace its value with a new string replacing the comma. So inArray(inArray.Length - 1) = inArray(inArray.Length - 1).Replace(",", "")

Comment: Would that line of code go beneath the current inArray = Split(inputString, ",") line?  Or should that line be altered?

Comment: Putting that new line of code beneath inArray=Split(inputString, ",") did not work .  I got a Compile Error:  Invalid qualifier.

Comment: add these two lines of code before your last line of stringOfUniques = s                                                                                                                                Dim lastComma As Integer = s.LastIndexOf(",")
s = s.Substring(0, lastComma)

Comment: this will find the last occurence of the comma character in your return string and grab the substring of s up to the last comma, thus excluding it, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Add your array's member strings as keys to a `Scripting.Dictionary` object.

Then you can produce your desired output string by joining the dictionary's keys.

```vb
Public Function stringOfUniques(inputString As String) As String
    Dim xVal As Variant
    Dim strTrimmed As String
    Dim dct As Object
    Set dct = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Each xVal In Split(inputString, ",")
        strTrimmed = Trim(xVal)
        If Len(strTrimmed) > 0 And Not dct.Exists(strTrimmed) Then
            dct.Add key:=strTrimmed, Item:=Null
        End If
    Next
    stringOfUniques = Join(dct.Keys, ", ")
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `instr` to test whether the item is already present in the string will fail for strings which contain other strings (e.g. for an input of `"pineapple,apple"`, your method would return `"pineapple"`).

To offer an alternative approach, consider the following function:

```
Function StringOfUniques(strArg As String) As String
    Dim col As New Collection, var
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each var In Split(strArg, ",")
        col.Add var, var
    Next var

    Dim rtn() As String, i As Long
    ReDim rtn(1 To col.Count)
    For i = 1 To col.Count
        rtn(i) = col(i)
    Next i

    StringOfUniques = Join(rtn, ",")
End Function
```

*Some Examples:*

```
?StringOfUniques("a,b,c")
a,b,c

?StringOfUniques("a,a,b,b,c,c")
a,b,c

?StringOfUniques("pineapple,apple")
pineapple,apple
```

This method constructs & populates a Collection object and relies on the requirement that the key associated with every item in a Collection must be unique (hence the use of `On Error Resume Next` to account for iterations which attempt to add an item whose key already appears in the Collection).

This approach of catching an anticipated error is perhaps not the most elegant solution, but likely to be more efficient than continually iterating over an array to test whether an item is already present.

Comment: @Katie, Could you please give an example of the input which you believe is still returning duplicates in the output?

Comment: @Katie Perhaps it's because your delimiters have a space? Try changing `","` to `", "` in my code.